# How to serialize XML document in python using xml.dom library

Tags: python, xml, dom

I'd like to know how I can serialize an XML document in python specifically using the [xml.dom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like:

```
xml.dom.ext.PrettyPrint(doc, open(name, "w"))
```

where `doc` is the XML document and `name` is the name of the file?

Or, if you have xml.dom.minidom, how about the `xml.dom.minidom.writexml` function?

Comment: The xml.dom.ext module doesn't seem to be a part of the standard library. Where does this library come from?

Comment: This is part of the PyXML package, not standard Python libraries.

Comment: It seems that PyXML is no longer maintained, according to a note on their download page on sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxml/files/ Is there a way to do this that uses a library that is maintained?

Comment: Regarding minidom, it strangely does not support serialization of namespaces: http://untidy.net/blog/2006/03/03/writing-xml-with-namespaces-from-minidom/ This is rather important for my application.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I appreciate it. I've spun off a new question to address what I feel may be the more general problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005641/is-python-bad-at-xml