# Is Python bad at XML?

Tags: python, xml, dom

#### EDIT

The use of the phrase "bad at XML" in this question has been a point of contention, so I'd like to start out by providing a very clear definition of what I mean by this term in this context: if support for standard XML APIs is poor, and forces one to use a language-specific API, in which namespaces seem to be an afterthought, then I would be inclined to characterize that language as being not as well suited to using XML as other mainstream languages that do not have these issues. "Bad at XML" is just a shorthand for these conditions, and I think it is a fair way to characterize it. As I will describe, my initial experience with Python has raised concerns about whether it fulfils these conditions; but, because in general my experience with Python has been quite positive, it seems likely that I'm missing something, thus motivating this question.

I'm trying to do some very simple XML processing with Python. I had initially hoped to be able to reuse my knowledge of standard W3C DOM API's, and happily found that the [xml.dom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) and [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) modules did a good job of supporting these API's. Unfortunately, however, serialization proved to be problematic, for the following reasons:

- xml.dom does not come with a serializer
- the PyXML library, which includes a serializer for xml.dom, is no longer maintained, AND
- minidom [does not support serialization of namespaces](http://untidy.net/blog/2006/03/03/writing-xml-with-namespaces-from-minidom/), even though namespaces are supported in the API

I looked through the list of other W3C-like libraries here:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml#W3CDOM-likelibraries

I found that many other libraries, such as 4Suite and libxml2dom, are also not maintained.

On the other hand, [itools](http://www.hforge.org/itools/) at first glance appears to be maintained, but there does not appear to be an Ubuntu/Debian package available, and so would be difficult to deploy and maintain.

At this point, it seemed like trying to use W3C DOM API's in my Python application was going to be dead-end, and I began to look at the ElementTree API. But the way the eTree API supports namespaces I think is horribly ugly, requiring one to use string concatenation every time an element in a particular namespace is created:

http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces

So, my question is, have I overlooked something, or is support for XML (in particular W3C DOM) actually quite bad in Python?

#### EDIT

Here follows a list of more precise questions, the answers to which would really help me:

- Is there reasonable support for W3C DOM in Python?
- If not `xml.dom`, do you use e.g. `etree` instead of W3C DOM?
- If so, which library is best, and how do you overcome the issues regarding namespacing in the API?
- If you use W3C DOM instead, are you aware of a library that implements serialization with support for namespaces?

Comment: Nice value judgement.  That's what makes for a good question.  Form an opinion and ask people to prove that your opinion is wrong.  Other than downvotes, what do you hope to get from a "loaded" value judgement like that?  Drop the opinion.  Drop the value judgement.  Drop the negativity.  Rephrase this to (1) define your problem and (2) ask for a solution.  Otherwise, you'll get nothing.

Comment: This is not meant to be a value judgement, but a serious question. I've tried to support it with links as well as I can to reflect the research I have done into this problem. The question is at the bottom, and I'll rephrase it here just to be clear: is there reasonable support for W3C DOM in Python? I think that's pretty neutral.

Comment: @echo-flow: "This is not meant to be a value judgement".  However.  It **is** a value judgement.  Drop the opinion. Drop the value judgement. Drop the negativity. Rephrase this to (1) define your problem and (2) ask for a solution.  Please.  "is there reasonable support for W3C DOM in Python?"  If that's your question, please drop the value judgement from the title and make that your title.

Comment: I maintain that the title is not meant to be a value judgement, and is meant to be a bit open-ended. I think this is fine, and allows people to talk about etree, and XML processing in Python in general. For example, the answer by @Seth about etree is also relevant to my question.

Comment: @echo-flow: I would rephrase the question as 'How is support for XML in Python?' Using the word 'bad' in the question isn't a really good way to start since it means you assume that it's bad. Don't do that.

Comment: "the title is not meant to be a value judgement."  How can you say that, when it **is** manifestly and obviously a value judgement.  "Bad at XML" is the best possible example of a value judgement.  There's no more concise or clear example of a value judgement.  That's all that phrase it.  It **is** a value judgement.  And.  It's not your question.  Please make it align with your question.

Comment: People sure become aggressively defensive when anyone *dares* to suggest that their pet language is something less than perfect.

Comment: Here is a complete explanation of my use of the phrase "bad at XML": if support for standard APIs is poor, and forces one to use a language-specific API, in which namespaces seem to be an afterthought,  then I would be inclined to characterize that language as being not as well suited to using XML as other mainstream languages that do not have these issues. The phrase "bad at XML" is just a shorthand for this, and I believe I have justified it well enough in the question to raise it as a legitimate concern. The purpose of this question is to gain a better understanding of these issues.

Comment: So, no value judgement. I genuinely want to know what is the right (most common, well-supported, best practices) approach to dealing with XML in Python. Based on the current responses, that would seem to be eTree and lxml.

Comment: "bad at XML" is a value judgement.  Explain all you want.  The phrase remains a value judgement.  "Bad" is a value judgement.  It isn't a question.  It's  a judgement.  " I genuinely want to know what is the right (most common, well-supported, best practices) approach to dealing with XML" If that's "genuine", then change the title to reflect that and drop the "bad".  If that's not genuine, then leave the value judgement in place.  Making the word "genuine" in your comment a clear lie.

Comment: @S.Lott: Rather than splitting hairs over the language I use to describe my concerns over XML and Python (which I still feel is technical, accurate, and acceptable), may I suggest that it would be more informative and productive for you to address the concerns I have raised in the original question, as others have already done. If Python is not bad at XML, it would be great if you could provide a detailed explanation as to why, because on the surface, there do appear to be serious issues there. This would help better my understanding, and the understanding of others who view this page as well.

Comment: @echo-flow: Not "hair-splitting". You enumerated your  "concerns".  You claim that there's have a "real" or "genuine" question, but rather than clarify the question in the title you want to focus on your "concerns".  The title is clear -- you found problems.   Since the there is no actual question -- it's a list of "concerns" -- really a complaint -- **and** you steadfastly refuse to modify the language to make it a proper question, I can't "answer".  I can't "solve".  It's a complaint.  You feel that Python is Bad at XML.  That's not a very good question.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I'm trying to gain a high-level understanding of what the situation is with XML in Python given my past experiences and perspective as an outsider, which have indeed raised some concerns, I believe justifiably. This is not a complaint, it is a high-level question, and it is possible to provide useful information toward its resolution, as others have already done. I'd appreciate any insight you could share into this.

Comment: Q: “Is Python bad at XML?” A: “No.” Question: “Have I overlooked something, or is support for XML (in particular W3C DOM) actually quite bad in Python?” A: “Yes, you have, and no, it isn't”. I'm glad I helped you by replying to the two different versions of your question.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: Of course, further information is needed for this to be a truly useful response. For example, do you use etree instead of W3C DOM? If so, which library is best, and how do you overcome the issues regarding namespacing in the API? If you use W3C DOM instead, are you aware of a library that implements serialization with support for namespaces?

Comment: This is a site for programmers; so you should ask the literal question(s) to which you want answers. What you did instead, was to declare your frustration and disappointment because Python as far as you looked into it did not match your expectations, and the questions you asked were not the ones to lead you to answers and caused (as it should be obvious) friction. You really need to edit your question and its title, unless your purpose was just to state your frustration, in which case you should delete the question.

Comment: After your comment, I helped indirectly by adding the questions you provided. You still need to edit the question title.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: Thanks for your edits. I've added a paragraph at the beginning of the question to make it clear that I am using "bad at XML" in a very restrictive and technical way. I think this should be acceptable, but if you have another suggestion for the title that uses different language, but captures what I state in the definition, and can be stated in a similar amount of space, I'd be open to it.

Comment: I get the impression that you are just looking for someone to validate your low opinion of Python XML support.  Lots of people successfully use python for advanced XML work, just because it doesn't work as you want or expect doesn't make it bad.  You definition of BAD, is purely subjective.

Comment: @mikerobi: "Lots of people successfully use python for advanced XML work" I think your answer would be more helpful if you could elaborate on this. Are they using etree or W3C DOM API? The python standard library or 3rd party libraries? I'd appreciate any insight you can offer into this. Thanks.

Comment: @echo-flow, all of the above.  You should be less concerned with what everyone else is using, and focus on finding the best solution for your problems.  If you took a survey, I would expect the most popular choices to be lxml and ElementTree, but the most popular solution isn't necessarily the best solution.  I happen to be a big fan of lxml, but I still use the less advanced Element API, and for specific problems, the ancient SAX parser. Stop fretting over features X&Y, sometimes different tools lead to different solutions.  Write some code with each and decide what's best for you.

Answer (score 4):

I would say python handles XML pretty well. The number of different libraries available speaks to that - you have lots of options. And if there are features missing from libraries that you would like to use, feel free to contribute some patches!

I personally use the DOM and lxml.etree (etree is *really* fast). However, I feel your pain about the namespace thing. I wrote a quick helper function to deal with it:

```
DEFAULT_NS = "http://www.domain.org/path/to/xml"

def add_xml_namespace(path, namespace=DEFAULT_NS):
    """Adds namespaces to an XPath-ish expression path for etree

    Test simple expression:
    >>> add_xml_namespace('image/namingData/fileBaseName')
    '{http://www.domain.org/path/to/xml}image/{http://www.domain.org/path/to/xml}namingData/{http://www.domain.org/path/to/xml}fileBaseName'

    More complicated expression
    >>> add_xml_namespace('.//image/*') 
    './/{http://www.domain.org/path/to/xml}image/*'

    >>> add_xml_namespace('.//image/text()')
    './/{http://www.domain.org/path/to/xml}image/text()'
    """
    pattern = re.compile(r'^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$')
    tags = path.split('/')
    for i in xrange(len(tags)):
        if pattern.match(tags[i]):
            tags[i] = "{%s}%s" % (namespace, tags[i])
    return '/'.join(tags)
```

I use it like so:

```
from lxml import etree
from utilities import add_xml_namespace as ns

tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
node = tree.get_root().find(ns('root/group/subgroup'))
# etc.
```

If you don't know the namespace ahead of time, you can extract it from a root node:

```
tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot().tag
namespace = root[1:root.index('}')]
ns = lambda path: add_xml_namespace(path, namespace)
...
```

Additional comment: There *is* a little work involved here, but work is necessary when dealing with XML. That's not a python issue, it's an XML issue.

Comment: "If you want it, submit a patch" is the most embarrassing open source one-liner.  (And, of course it's a Python issue--it's not XML's fault if a Python API is missing functions and makes you do the work, it's the API's fault.)

Comment: For an end-user application, it sounds bad, but for a library written for programmers, what's wrong with that?  I've had to use many proprietary libraries (especially in less-dynamic languages) where the situation was basically "If you need one trivial feature we didn't think to include, #@!$ off".  People afraid of writing a little code aren't the ones downloading XML libraries in the first place...

Comment: @Ken: It's an entirely different situation when the library is no longer maintained, or left in an ambiguous state, as seems to be the case for many of these python XML libraries. Maintaining a library is much more work than simply submitting a patch.

Comment: @echo-flow: I don't understand what's your problem with `lxml`. I for one am very happy with it, and my current project revolves **solely** around XML! What features are you missing? (Serialization is simply `etree.tostring(the_node, formatting_and_encoding_options)`)

Comment: @delnan: I think the ElementTree APIs involving namespaces are unfortunate, and do not seem fully thought-out in comparison with W3C DOM. Requiring one to do string manipulation to create a namespaced element, or extract the namespace from an existing element, seems like a brittle and hacked-together solution compared with DOM APIs. With that said, since I originally asked this question, I have been using lxml in my project, as that seems to be the popular choice, and it's been working well enough for me. It's just not optimal. Do you find it difficult working with namespaces in your project?

Comment: @echo-flow: Although the documents in questions make heavy use of namespaces (IIRC, I didn't encounter a single tag that's not in some namespace while testing), it was only a minor annoyance. For the most part, it meant calling `.format()` once before evaluating an XPath query, and ignoring the `{...}` while reading debugging output. Maybe I'm just lucky since I read the XMLs into a custom, much more lightweight data structure for processing and convert it back to an etree for output (preserving namespaces, but that's trivial) - so only those parts need to deal with namespaces.

Comment: Having a plethora of external options for something so common is considered a shortcoming in Python.

Comment: @delnan: thank you for the useful reply. @Edmund: could you please elaborate on what you mean? What are the "external options" here and what is common?

Answer (score 1):

Python is great at handling XML, I consider [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) to be the best xml library I have ever worked with, it is powerful and significantly simpler the DOM.  The namespace handling took some getting used to, but I think it is another great way lxml keeps things simple.

**EDIT**

After re reading the question, it is unclear exactly whether the the author meant the serialization of python objects, or just the DOM tree.  The portion of my answer bellow assumed the former.

XML serialization is a completely different issue.  Personal I don't think it is very important.  Most XML serializers produce output that its pretty specific to the language or runtime, which defeats the purpose of having such an open format.  I realize that there are some generic XML serialization schema, but Python provides 2 solutions that are superior for 95% of situations, Pickling and JSON.

If your application doesn't have to share objects with non-python systems, Pickling is the fastest and most powerful serialization solution you will find.  JSON is significantly faster to parse and generate, and much easier to work with than XML.  JSON has plenty of limitations, but it is frequently easier to work around them, than deal with the headaches of XML.

There are plenty of other serialization formats that, depending on the application, I would recommend ahead of XML (E.G.: Google Protocol Buffers, or YAML.)

Also, don't forget about SAX.  Event driven parsers are only useful for reading XML, but I have found that it is still the best solution for some problems.

Answer (score 1):

> But the way the eTree API supports namespaces I think is horribly ugly, requiring one to use string concatenation every time an element in a particular namespace is created

Here's how you create an element with a namespace in .NET's `System.Linq.Xml` DOM:

```
XNamespace ns = "my-namespace";
XElement elm = new XElement(ns + "foo");
```

Here's how you create an element in a namespace in lxml:

```
ns = "{my-namespace}"
elm = etree.Element(ns + "foo")
```

I'm not seeing horrible ugliness here. In fact, the developers of the .NET API have bent over backwards, creating base classes that support operator overloading, to make it possible for their API to handle namespaces as intuitively as `lxml`'s does.

How this is uglier than the W3C DOM requiring you to use different methods to create elements with and without namespaces is beyond me.

Comment: More problematic than creation is querying. To get the namespace of an element using W3C DOM, you simply access its namespaceURI property; to get the tag name, it's localName. If you look at @Seth's example, you can see that accessing the namespaceURI using etree requires the following invocation "root[1:root.index('}')]". I think this is not as clean. If there's a better way to do this, however, that would be good to know.

Comment: I agree with you there; it's kind of dumb that `Element` doesn't have a `localName` property.  On the other hand, if you're querying XML by iterating over DOM objects and looking at the names of elements, instead of using XPath, you're probably making other mistakes too.